# SDL + emacs + Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, emacs, sdl

I'm trying to use C++ SDL code in emacs and compile it under Mac OS X Lion. In XCode with SDL's template and framework everything works fine, but when I try to compile some sample SDL code found on the internet: http://pastebin.com/cWH5X8Hu I can't make it work using emacs. I always receive such errors: http://pastebin.com/BZ3xJsmv. The command I use is `g++ -o sdltest main.cpp sdl-config --cflags --libs`.
I've installed SDL from source and I have no idea what can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to link against an incompatible version of the libraries, you need to get an X86_64 version of lib SDL.

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libSDL.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

This bug is not to do with emacs at all.